# Jenkins different schedule for different configurations

Tags: continuous-integration, jenkins

I am working with a multi-configuration Jenkins project. The two configuration axes are Win/Linux and 32/64-bit. I would like to build the primary configuration (32-bit Windows) whenever version control changes, but to only build the other configurations once weekly (just to make sure that they stay reasonably up to date).

Is it possible to achieve this schedule without breaking the project up into multiple individual projects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not through Jenkins directly at this point AFAIK. There is only one time handler per job, and the multi-configuration is a single job, it has a single timer.

There is a hack, but it will be tough, and I'm not sure of the exact script required, but if you can check the day of the week, you could try something like this in your script:

```
if (day == Sunday |OR| $NODE_NAME == win32), then:
  <carry out build steps here>
finish
```

This way:

- If the day is Sunday, all steps will be carried out regardless of Node.
- If the node name is win32, the step swill be carried out too.
- However, if day is not Sunday and $NODE_NAME is win64 or linux32 or linux64, no steps will be carried out.

Note that `$NODE_NAME` is a standard Jenkins environment variable. However, **this assumes that your build is done through either "Execute Shell" or "Execute Windows Batch"**

Is there any reason the others shouldn't build at the same time?

You could create two jobs, one for your primary so it is a free-style job, and the other as a multi-configuration with Win64/Linux and leave that on a separate, weekly timer.

Comment: Thanks very much, clever idea to put the date check in the build script. I think both of you are probably right that I should just build all 4 configurations each time. I'll just use the win32 build as a "touchstone" so it reports failing builds right away.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider this:

**Why not build ALL available configurations EVERY time**?
- after all, that is the whole idea of Continuous Integration...

Can drop the artifacts of those builds after a short period of time,
so they don't clog your disk, but if anything breaks your build - you will know it right away.

Can also set the slaves' queue to run a single job at a time, so the builds don't overload the build-servers.

The other solution requires:

- Two "starters" for your build
- All slaves to be available

Set **Job_A1** as a weekly scheduler that triggers **Job_B** (the main multi-configuration build process).
Set **Job_A2** to run **Job_B** whenever there are source-code changes.
Set **Job_B** to know if it was triggered by **Job_A1** or **Job_A2** (can pass its name as a parameter),
and also set **Job_B** to ignore calls from **Job_A2** ("exit 0"), if the current config. differs from **Windows-32bit**.

This way, all 4 configurations will run whenever there are source-control changes, but only one will actually build.

Good luck!

Comment: Very creative solution! I think you're probably right that I should just build all the configurations each time though. Thanks